# login to system without user id

Tags: ssh

I want to remotely log in to our server through my account. but each time I don't want to enter the ID (I just want to enter password). how can I save my user id for the next time that I want to log in?
[image]

Comment: What does "remotely" mean?  An ILO?  Dial-up?

Comment: What about putting `ssh user@machine` into a script. If you also use a key, then you can securely avoid the password as well.

Comment: @JdeBP remotely means from anywhere to our server. I am using putty.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for defining remotely (we are not good with words) and for telling us that it does not work (We were wondering why you asked).

Comment: What OS are you logging in from?

Comment: I am logging from windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your putty setup, go to `Connection -> Data` and set the Auto-login username to your user id. Save the session. From then on, the username will be entered for you.

Comment: Thank you. that's it. if you have any other options please share it with me.

Answer (score 0):

You could also configure "password-less ssh" aka public key login.
This involves a few more steps which you'll only need to perform once, which is described in detail in the PuTTY Manual [Chapter 8](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/putty-manuals/0.68/Chapter8.html) and [Chapter 9](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/putty-manuals/0.68/Chapter9.html) (the latter describing how to use a key agent so that you can use a password-protected private key which you only need to unlock by password once per session (boot) on your client).

It's slightly more than you asked for, since you don't even have to put in your password every time you use PuTTY.